# put stream from tcpdump into an array - which python version should i use?

Tags: python, stream

i want to use python in combination with tcpdump to put the generated stream from tcpdump into a more readable way. There are some fields in the streams with interesting values.

I found some stuff here at stackoverflow regarding python and tcpdump but in my mind the best way is to put it in an array.

After this is done i want to read some fields out of the array, and than it can be cleared and used for the next network frame.

Can somebody give me some hints, how this can be done?

Comment: What did you try so far? Show us some code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [python libpcap library](http://pylibpcap.sourceforge.net/) to capture network packets directly from python :).

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `Scapy` sniffing function `sniff`, append the captured packets to a list and do your extraction process.